# returning a multidimensional pointer in c

Tags: c

error lvalue returned as left operand of assignment
What is the error in this program;

```
int(*matrix)[row][col];
int i = 0;
if(n == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < no_matrices; i++)
    {
        printf("Matrix %d", i + 1);
        (matrix + i) = GetMatrixU(row, col); // (error here)
    }
}

int* GetMatrixU(int row, int col)

    srand(time(NULL));
    int(* matrix)[col] = malloc(col*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j ++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand()%100;
        }
    }
    return matrix[];
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on? Post a complete (but SMALL) program with the error.

Comment: Not providing enough information to diagnose the *real* problem is the most immediate error. Not allocating enough space is somewhat secondary to that. Syntax errors are just salt in the wound.

Comment: `int(*matrix)[row][col];` Is the same as `int *matrix[row][col];` ?

Comment: @Amir no, it isn't. The former is a single pointer to an array of array, the latter is an array of array of pointers.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I thought it was the same and I was going to answer it as array of array of pointer to int

Comment: It is best practice on StackOverflow to provide a short snippet of code that demonstrates the problem, and the snippet *should actually work*.  What you posted won't compile or work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
(matrix + i) = GetMatrixU(row, col);
```

This tries to make an assignment.  The expression on the right is evaluated; this is the "r-value" ("r" for "right").  Then the result should be assigned to the expression on the left, which is the "l-value" ("l" for "left").

Well, `(matrix + i)` is not a valid l-value.  `matrix` by itself is a single pointer to a two-dimensional array.  In C, you can't just specify a pointer value and assign to it; you must use the `*` operator to *dereference* the array, and assign through that.

Here is a short code sample that shows how to dereference a pointer, and then repeats your error.

```
main()
{
    int a[10];
    *(a + 1) = 0;  // proper use of * to dereference
    a + 1 = 0; // will not compile; error is "l-value required"
}
```

But in C, there is a shortcut way to add to a pointer and then dereference it.  It is the use of square brackets and an index value:

```
a[1] = 0;  // index the array
```

In C, the expressions `*(a + i)` and `a[i]` mean exactly the same thing, by definition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Accessing_elements

It looks like you are trying to create a random matrix, one row at a time.  And you are allocating memory for each row.  Your basic matrix declaration should be an array of pointers to rows.

```
int *matrix[rows];

for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    // either of these lines will work; pick just one
    *(matrix + i) = AllocateRandomRow(cols);  // explicit add-and-dereference
    matrix[i] = AllocateRandomRow(cols);  // simpler: just index array
}
```

I favor the second, simpler syntax for solving this problem.  You are indexing an array; just use the square brackets.

Here is a free online text that describes how to dynamically allocate a matrix.

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of simpler case to understand this more complex case:

```
int b = 4;
int *a = &b; // Allowed and works because a is a pointer to an integer
a+1 = 5; // Not allowed no idea about the type of a+1 and it could be used!!
```

Why this relates to your problem ?

```
int(*matrix)[5][5];
printf("%p\n",matrix);
printf("%p\n",matrix+1);
```

**Output**

```
0xb7753000
0xb7753064
```

Difference between the above pointers is of 6*16 + 4 = 100. This number is nothing but row*col*sizeOf(int) = 5*5*4 = 100

Therefore, what you want to do was accessing the cells in matrix, however what you are actually doing is trying to access a memory that your not allowed to use as in the first simple example.

**Example of what you are actually doing vs what you wanted the program to do:**

```
int(*matrix)[5][5];
matrix + 0 => address of matrix
matrix + 1 => address of matrix + 100 bytes (you expected + 4 bytes instead)
matrix + 2 => address of matrix + 200 bytes (you expected + 8 bytes instead)
etc...
```